# Фильтрация массива объектов по нескольким параметрам, UICollectionView, Swift

Tags: swift, поиск, search, filter, uicollectionview

Добрый день, у меня есть массив объектов, который использует collectionView для отображения ячеек. Присутствует поиск, согласно которому нужно его  фильтровать.

При фильтрации нужно использовать несколько параметров объекта: имя, фамилия и отчество.

```
 var customers = [Customer]()
 var filteredData = [Customer]()

class Customer: NSObject {
    name:String!
    surname:String!
    patronomic:String!
}
```

Как прописать фильтрацию в методе:

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController)

self.filteredData = ????

collectionView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Фильтрация осуществляется по всем полям или по выборочным?

Comment: @Axazeano параметров около 10, но поиск нужно будет осуществлять по нескольким из них, 3-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
filteredData = customers.filter({( customer : Customer) -> Bool in

                    let x1 =  "\(customer.name!) " + "\(customer.surname!) " + "\(customer.patronymic!) "
                    let y1 =  "\(customer.surname!) " + "\(customer.name!) " + "\(customer.patronymic!) "
                    let z1 =  "\(customer.patronymic!) " + "\(customer.name!) " + "\(customer.patronymic!) "
                    let x2 =  "\(customer.patronymic!) " + "\(customer.surname!) " + "\(customer.name!) "
                    let y2 =  "\(customer.surname!) " + "\(customer.patronymic!) " + "\(customer.name!) "
                    let z2 =  "\(customer.name!) " + "\(customer.patronymic!) " + "\(customer.surname!) "

                    return x1.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())||y1.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())||z1.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())||x2.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())||y2.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())||z2.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
                 })
```

Answer (score 1):

На ум приходит следующее решение:

Создаём перечисление с типами фильтров и методом для фильтрации:

```
enum CustomerFilter {
    case filterByName(customers: [Customer], name: String)
    case filterBySurname(customers: [Customer], surname: String)
    // ещё какие-нибудь фильтры

    func filter() -> [Customers] {
        switch self {
            case .filterByName(let customers, let name):
                return customers.filter { $0.name == name }
            case .filterBySurname(let customers, let surname)
                return customers.filter { $0.surname == surname }
            // ещё какие-нибудь фильтры
        }
    }
}
```

А затем используем таким образом

```
let filteredCustomers = CustomerFilter.filterByName(customers: rawCustomers, name:  "Vasya").filter()
```

---

Update:
Написал составные фильтры:

```
class Customer {
    init(name: String, surname: String, patronomic: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.patronomic = name
    }

    var name:String
    var surname:String
    var patronomic:String
}

enum CustomerFilter {
    case name(name: String)
    case surname(surname: String)

    func compare(with customer: Customer) -> Bool {
        switch self {
        case .name(let name):
            return name == customer.name
        case .surname(let surname):
            return surname == customer.surname
        }
    }
}

let filters = [CustomerFilter.name(name: "Vasya"),
               CustomerFilter.surname(surname: "Petrov")]

let rawCustomers = [Customer(name: "Vasya", surname: "Petrov", patronomic: "1"),
                    Customer(name: "Vova", surname: "Petrov", patronomic: "2")]

let filteredCustomers = rawCustomers.filter { customer in
    var result = true
    filters.forEach { filter in
        print(customer.name)
        if !filter.compare(with: customer) {
            result = false
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш вариант! попробовал, он работает, но не совсем так, как нужно:
К примеру есть у меня два параметра `name = "Джон"; surname = "Траволта"` и ваш код фильтрует только если будет введено имя целиком - "Джон", а "Дж" - не учитывает, так же нужно что бы можно было в строку ввести оба параметра одновременно - "Джон Травол" - и уже все отсортировано, как думаете, что нужно изменить?

Comment: Я обновил свой комментарий

Comment: имя, фамилия и отчество могут быть в любом ведь порядке, кто-то будет искать вписывая сначала имя, кто-то - фамилию, и в итоге это один стринги ведь. Ваш код подразумевает, что я знаю, что человек вписывает, имя фамилию или отчество (тк вносятся они раздельно), но я конечно же не знаю этого, у меня просто есть строка с этими параметрами в рандомном порядке

Comment: Можете создать функцию для парсинга входной строки. Скорее всего у вас `key-value` (где `key` - поле, для которого производится фильтрация, `value` - значение для фильтрации) записи в строке. Зная `key` и `value` вы всегда можете создать `CustomerFilter`